# error creating new kernel in AMLs notebook

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

i am attempting to create a new kernel in an AMLs notebook.  It turns out that it doesn’t matter which kernel I am trying to create, because it doesn't get that far.  ☹

i am following the steps here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-terminal#add-new-kernels

my full terminal session text is below.

the error i get is:

```
InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink')
```

thanks for any suggestions or pointers.

```
Welcome to Azure Machine Learning Terminal

Type "git clone [url]" to clone a repo                      
Type "git --help" to learn about Git CLI                
Type "az ml --help" to learn about Azure ML CLI           


azureuser@qnotebook:/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/qnotebook/code$ cd ~/cloudfiles/code/Users/delbertm/amls-qc 
azureuser@qnotebook:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/delbertm/amls-qc$ 
azureuser@qnotebook:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/delbertm/amls-qc$ conda create --name qsharp-env
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.9.2
  latest version: 4.10.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /anaconda/envs/qsharp-env



Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate qsharp-env
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

azureuser@qnotebook:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/delbertm/amls-qc$ conda activate qsharp-env
(qsharp-env) azureuser@qnotebook:~/cloudfiles/code/Users/delbertm/amls-qc$ conda install pip
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.9.2
  latest version: 4.10.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /anaconda/envs/qsharp-env

  added / updated specs:
    - pip


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _openmp_mutex-4.5          |            1_gnu          22 KB
    ca-certificates-2021.5.25  |       h06a4308_1         112 KB
    certifi-2021.5.30          |   py39h06a4308_0         139 KB
    ld_impl_linux-64-2.35.1    |       h7274673_9         586 KB
    libffi-3.3                 |       he6710b0_2          50 KB
    libgcc-ng-9.3.0            |      h5101ec6_17         4.8 MB
    libgomp-9.3.0              |      h5101ec6_17         311 KB
    libstdcxx-ng-9.3.0         |      hd4cf53a_17         3.1 MB
    ncurses-6.2                |       he6710b0_1         817 KB
    pip-21.1.2                 |   py39h06a4308_0         1.8 MB
    python-3.9.5               |       h12debd9_4        22.6 MB
    readline-8.1               |       h27cfd23_0         362 KB
    setuptools-52.0.0          |   py39h06a4308_0         724 KB
    sqlite-3.35.4              |       hdfb4753_0         981 KB
    tk-8.6.10                  |       hbc83047_0         3.0 MB
    tzdata-2020f               |       h52ac0ba_0         113 KB
    wheel-0.36.2               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          33 KB
    xz-5.2.5                   |       h7b6447c_0         341 KB
    zlib-1.2.11                |       h7b6447c_3         103 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        39.9 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _libgcc_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main
  _openmp_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/linux-64::ca-certificates-2021.5.25-h06a4308_1
  certifi            pkgs/main/linux-64::certifi-2021.5.30-py39h06a4308_0
  ld_impl_linux-64   pkgs/main/linux-64::ld_impl_linux-64-2.35.1-h7274673_9
  libffi             pkgs/main/linux-64::libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2
  libgcc-ng          pkgs/main/linux-64::libgcc-ng-9.3.0-h5101ec6_17
  libgomp            pkgs/main/linux-64::libgomp-9.3.0-h5101ec6_17
  libstdcxx-ng       pkgs/main/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng-9.3.0-hd4cf53a_17
  ncurses            pkgs/main/linux-64::ncurses-6.2-he6710b0_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/linux-64::openssl-1.1.1k-h27cfd23_0
  pip                pkgs/main/linux-64::pip-21.1.2-py39h06a4308_0
  python             pkgs/main/linux-64::python-3.9.5-h12debd9_4
  readline           pkgs/main/linux-64::readline-8.1-h27cfd23_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/linux-64::setuptools-52.0.0-py39h06a4308_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/linux-64::sqlite-3.35.4-hdfb4753_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/linux-64::tk-8.6.10-hbc83047_0
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2020f-h52ac0ba_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/linux-64::xz-5.2.5-h7b6447c_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/linux-64::zlib-1.2.11-h7b6447c_3


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
_openmp_mutex-4.5    | 22 KB     | ########################################################################################################################################################################################################################################8                                                                                   |  74% WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/lib/libgomp.so.1.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/licenses/LICENSE.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/fortomp/CMakeLists.txt.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/fortomp/test_fort.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/aligned_alloc.c.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/aligned_alloc.cpp.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/yum_requirements.txt.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/config.old.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgcc-devel.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/make_tool_links.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/LICENSE.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-gdb.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgcc.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgcc-no-gomp.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-g++.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/uclibc.config.minimal.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/hello-world.cpp.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-openmp_impl.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgfortran.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/build.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-gcc.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/uclibc.config.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-binutils.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/c11threads.c.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/conda_build_config.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-duma.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libstdc++.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgomp.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libstdc++-devel.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/meta.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/write_ctng_config.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-gfortran.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/install-openmp_impl.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/meta.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/test/run_test.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/hash_input.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/run_exports.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/repodata_record.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/about.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/index.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/paths.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/files.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/git.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/lib/libgomp.so.1.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/licenses/LICENSE.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/fortomp/CMakeLists.txt.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/fortomp/test_fort.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/aligned_alloc.c.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/tests/aligned_alloc.cpp.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/yum_requirements.txt.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/config.old.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgcc-devel.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/make_tool_links.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/LICENSE.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-gdb.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgcc.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgcc-no-gomp.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-g++.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/uclibc.config.minimal.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/hello-world.cpp.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-openmp_impl.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgfortran.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/build.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-gcc.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/uclibc.config.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-binutils.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/c11threads.c.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/conda_build_config.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-duma.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libstdc++.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libgomp.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-libstdc++-devel.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/meta.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/write_ctng_config.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/parent/install-gfortran.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/install-openmp_impl.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/recipe/meta.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/test/run_test.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/hash_input.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/run_exports.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/repodata_record.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/about.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/index.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/paths.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/files.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu/info/git.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
_openmp_mutex-4.5    | 22 KB     | ### | 100% 
readline-8.1         | 362 KB    | ### | 100% 
tzdata-2020f         | 113 KB    | ### | 100% 
ncurses-6.2          | 817 KB    | ### | 100% 
xz-5.2.5             | 341 KB    | ### | 100% 
pip-21.1.2           | 1.8 MB    | ### | 100% 
zlib-1.2.11          | 103 KB    | ### | 100% 
setuptools-52.0.0    | 724 KB    | ### | 100% 
ca-certificates-2021 | 112 KB    | ### | 100% 
libgcc-ng-9.3.0      | 4.8 MB    | ### | 100% 
libgomp-9.3.0        | 311 KB    | ### | 100% 
libstdcxx-ng-9.3.0   | 3.1 MB    | ### | 100% 
ld_impl_linux-64-2.3 | 586 KB    | ### | 100% 
python-3.9.5         | 22.6 MB   | ### | 100% 
certifi-2021.5.30    | 139 KB    | ### | 100% 
libffi-3.3           | 50 KB     | ### | 100% 
sqlite-3.35.4        | 981 KB    | ### | 100% 
wheel-0.36.2         | 33 KB     | ### | 100% 
tk-8.6.10            | 3.0 MB    | ### | 100% 

InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive /anaconda/pkgs/_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_gnu.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCould not unlink')
```

Answer (score 1):

i was able to get this to work by:

1. deleting and recreating the Compute Instance
2. following these instructions:
   a. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-terminal
   b. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/install-jupyter-qdk?tabs=tabid-conda